# best practice for synchronising plone content with content on the file system

Tags: plone

For instance if I had a folder in plone which a set of PDFs and this is synced with a folder somewhere on the filesystem. If a PDF is deleted in Plone the PDF should be removed from the disk folder. If a PDF is added in the disk folder then it appears in the Plone Folder.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any need for the PDF to live in the filesystem? I mean, if you allow users to upload them on Plone, if later the file is removed is really removed, no need to sync anything.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 addons for this ([Reflecto](http://plone.org/products/reflecto) and [PloneLocalFolderNG](http://plone.org/products/plonelocalfolderng)) but unfortunately they both are not yet plone4 compatible. I think that by now the only option still open is the [webdav](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/webdav).

Comment: Worth noting that as of this writing [Reflecto](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.Reflecto/2.5.1) **is** compatible with Plone 4